# Why declare inside of $(function () { ... })?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The application I am looking at loads an external javascript file which looks like this:

```
$(function () {

    // Don't allow browser caching of forms
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    var dialogs = {};

    var getValidationSummaryErrors = function ($form) {
        // We verify if we created it beforehand
        ...
        ...
        }
        return errorSummary;
    };
```

I understand that the file setups up some variables and also declares a function called getValidationSummaryErrors.

What I don't understand is why is this all within

```
$(function () {  ... }
```

What's the purpose of this? Can I not just declare the variable and things inside the flat file without the "$(function () { }" ?

Comment: Maybe also something with closure

Comment: JavaScript is a dangerously powerful language. I recommend you to view Doug Crockford 's video if you haven't. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: Closure explained in non-technical term. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6472397/310767

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$(function() { ... });` is just short for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, which ensures that the code is not executed until the DOM is ready, otherwise some code that affects the DOM may not work properly.

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It also avoids polluting the global namespace.

Comment: True, but you don't need jQuery for that. A `(function() { ... })()` used properly would do.

Comment: This is precisely why I'd rather see people use `$(document).ready(function() {...})` instead of `$(function() { ... });` because the former is so much more obvious what it does.

Comment: I suggest to use something like `jQuery(function($) { ... });` because you build a automatic noConflict system and you always can use the normal `$` in the code inside this function.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {  ... });
```

Means that the function will run after the page (DOM part) is loaded, not when the code gets parsed. This you can make sure that the page is loaded faster, and also everything necessary is available for the javascript to run.

Answer (score 3):

`$()` is shortcut for `jQuery.ready()`, which executes code after page DOM is fully loaded. Sometimes you want to make sure that document is ready before you do certain things.

Answer (score 2):

This is a concise notation for $(document).ready(function() {...}) ". **NOTE :** the jQuery document ready fires when the DOM has been loaded. It doesn't wait for entire page (included images and the like) to load.

Practically, any script that you put into the `<head>` executes immediately i.e. if the Script interacts with the DOM it needs to be ready.

Thirdly it is needed for separations of concerns. Ideally your javaScript and HTML are in separate files. If you follow this you will not have any in-line script tags in your HTML at all.